# Throws "IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint" while publishing a page in Django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Recently I migrated my local django + django-cms site to production server using following methods:

- moved code to production server and populated db schema using makemigration and migrate commands
- I exported the data using Pycharm's inbuilt database tool via "Dump data to File(s)" > "SQL-Insert-Statements.sql.groovy", the exported file had only insert statements and no other sql statement.
- I copy pasted and executed these statements in query tool window using pgAdmin 4
- I executed sql statements for reset sequences which I got from "python manage.py sqlsequencereset   ..." command

Now after doing all this the website is working fine but on the admin side I can edit the page and it keeps the changes in database but throws error when I click on "publish page changes" button.

Here is the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cms_cmsplugin_path_4917bb44_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (path)=(0007) already exists.
```

Complete error stack:

```
[15/Jul/2020 21:13:40] "POST /en/admin/cms/page/45/en/publish/ HTTP/1.1" 500 25121
Internal Server Error: /en/admin/cms/page/45/en/publish/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cms_cmsplugin_path_4917bb44_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (path)=(0007) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py", line 1125, in publish_page
    all_published = page.publish(language)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 987, in publish
    self._copy_contents(public_page, language)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 633, in _copy_contents
    placeholder.copy_plugins(target_placeholder, language=language)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/placeholdermodel.py", line 580, in copy_plugins
    root_plugin=root_plugin,
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/utils/plugins.py", line 214, in copy_plugins_to_placeholder
    new_plugin = CMSPlugin.add_root(instance=new_plugin)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py", line 625, in add_root
    return MP_AddRootHandler(cls, **kwargs).process()
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py", line 345, in process
    newobj.save()
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangocms_text_ckeditor/models.py", line 64, in save
    super(AbstractText, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/pluginmodel.py", line 270, in save
    super(CMSPlugin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 776, in save_base
    parent_inserted = self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in _save_parents
    force_insert=parent_inserted,
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1368, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/john/project1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cms_cmsplugin_path_4917bb44_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (path)=(0007) already exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

something similar happened to me after migrating from sqlite to postgresql and I thought it was a problem with this.
But searching I found that it was a Treebeard 4.5 problem.

And the solution that worked for me was to Rollback to version 4.4.

https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/issues/6980